# how to store a mac id and int value to mapping in c

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a list of mac ids and value

```
mac id1 : B827E82D398E  value : 0
mac id2 : B827E82D398E  value : 1
```

how to store and  compare the  mac id and  get a value in c??

Comment: Two common ways to map from a key to some data is either a hash-table or some kind of a tree. Please do some more research (and read books or take classes) About common data structures and algorithms.

Comment: Or for something extremely simple, an array or a list of structures, where you simply iterate over all the structures until you find the ones you need.

Comment: if have any example kindly post for reference

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your question, and how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt.